# How to create HTML column in Sharepoint?

Tags: column, html

Today one of are lab tech deleted the Java Script that would take the HTML in a list and display it. Dose anyone know what script it is?

What im trying to display:

```
<span style='position:relative;display:inline-block;width:100%;'><span style='width:100%;display:inline-block;text-align:center;border:1px solid;background-color:White;position:absolute;'>Regular</span><span style='display:inline-block;width: 100%;background-filter:alpha(opacity=20);opacity:0.2;color:White;text-align:left;border:1px solid; color:#000000;z-index:-1>Regular'</span></span>
```

Comment: I'm guessing this is a custom script? Maybe this one.. http://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2008/09/01/using-calculated-columns-to-write-html/ ?

Comment: Like Kit mentioned, the only way this would work is through the HTML calculated columns.